# grouping into rectangles on a binary grid

Tags: algorithm, grid

I've got a binary grid representing texture pixels to be updated.
The cost to upload these pixels can be roughly divided in a fixed (similar to a header in some protocol) and a dynamic part which is determined by the upload size. Both are system dependent but can be measured.

This means that the costs come for each rectangle where the fixed costs (the transfer overhead) are always the same.

The cost function itself can vary from system to system; in most cases it is best approximated by a linear function like a line equation, f.e. cost_per_rectangle = fixed_costs + dynamic_costs * rectangle_size, or short c = f + s * d. But it may well be that this function becomes logarithmic or exponential, like c = f + s * log(d) or c = f + s * d^(1+some).

Here are some real world measurements, plotted in a linear and a y-log diagram with sizes from 2 to 1M where X is the number of points and Y the time in us:

[image: upload performance]

I'm looking for an algorithm which can calculate rectangles which cover all of the cells marked for update while minimizing the total costs.

The rectangles may overlap.

Because the costs for calculating these rectangles add up to the total costs, i'm looking for an efficient but not perfect algorithm, although it would be very nice to hear about the perfect solution and if it's NP-complete or not.

At the moment, I have no idea how to approach this best, only a vague feeling that maybe kd-trees could help.

Here are some images of possible results for an example grid:
[image: four corner extreme]

[image: diagonal]

[image: L or X]

[image: overlapping]

I did some try and error tests with the diagonal example and found an optimal rectangle size for the diagonal example by comparing upload times for all possible sizes.

Comment: This is currently very unclear - can you add some examples to explain all of this?

Comment: @Dukeling i've added some example pictures.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time understanding the costs. Is the fixed cost once-off (for the grid) or once for every rectangle? Is the dynamic part linearly proportional to the number of cells sent (over all rectangles) (e.g. 2 units per cell, so a 2x2 would cost 2\*4=8 units, and a 5x5 and a 3x3 rectangle would cost 2\*(25+9)=68 units) or is there some other scaling? Are you looking for an algorithm that aims to minimise overall cost for any given fixed and dynamic costs, or do you have some costs and you're just looking for an algorithm for those specific costs?

Comment: @Dukeling good point! I tried to update the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that somebody drew a lot of rectangles on top of your picture, with rectangles nested into rectangles, but no two rectangles overlapping. You could use dynamic programming on trees to work out a subset of rectangles to choose that covers all of the cells marked for update. Think of the nesting as a tree structure. Working from the leaves up, compute the minimal cost at each node of covering all of the cells marked for update underneath that node: it is either the sum of the costs calculated by the children of that node or the cost of the single rectangle associated with that node - whichever is smallest. (In fact you can shrink that single rectangle if there aren't cells needing update close to its edges)

How to get a good tree structure to start with? Two come to mind. One is the Quad Tree decomposition, which recursively divides each large rectangle into four smaller ones, and then subdivides these smaller ones, and so on. The other would be to form a minimum spanning tree of the cells needing update, probably using Manhattan distance, and to use this tree structure as a tree of rectangles, with each node having a rectangle just big enough to be the bounding box for its descendants.